# Getting error while opening app in Heroku

Tags: heroku, python

I have deployed an application in python and django which is successfully deployed in Heroku.

But when I am trying to open there it is showing error as  below - [image]

After checking in logs it is showing as -

[image]

Why this is showing error ? -

> After adding all files like procfile,etc this above error got vanishes.
>   but again getting error after successful deployment like

Environment:

Request Method: GET
Request URL: https://studentrestframework.herokuapp.com/api/students/

Django Version: 2.1.4
Python Version: 3.6.5
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'rest_framework',
 'myapp']
Installed Middleware:
('whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware')

Traceback:

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in _execute
  85.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

The above exception (relation "myapp_student" does not exist
LINE 1: ..."last_name", "myapp_student"."university_id" FROM "myapp_stu...
                                                             ^
) was the direct cause of the following exception:

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  126.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  124.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py" in wrapped_view
  54.         return view_func(*args, **kwargs)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/viewsets.py" in view
  116.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in dispatch
  495.             response = self.handle_exception(exc)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in handle_exception
  455.             self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in dispatch
  492.             response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/mixins.py" in list
  48.         return Response(serializer.data)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py" in data
  768.         ret = super(ListSerializer, self).data

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py" in data
  262.                 self._data = self.to_representation(self.instance)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py" in to_representation
  686.             self.child.to_representation(item) for item in iterable

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in **iter**
  268.         self._fetch_all()

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in _fetch_all
  1186.             self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in **iter**
  54.         results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in execute_sql
  1065.             cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  100.             return super().execute(sql, params)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  68.         return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in _execute_with_wrappers
  77.         return executor(sql, params, many, context)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in _execute
  85.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py" in **exit**
  89.                 raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in _execute
  85.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

Exception Type: ProgrammingError at /api/students/
Exception Value: relation "myapp_student" does not exist
LINE 1: ..."last_name", "myapp_student"."university_id" FROM "myapp_stu...
                                                             ^

Comment: Silly question: Did you actually set a web worker? `heroku ps:scale web=1`

Comment: Hi sfdcfox, thanks for reply. I am new to it. can u plz tell me what to do for it.

Comment: Again, did you run the command to actually start the server? The error suggests you did not.

Comment: No, I didn't. But when I m trying to run getting error as belows -                                    Scaling dynos... !
 !    Couldn't find that process type (web).

Scaling dynos... !
 !    Couldn't find that process type (web).

Comment: Do you have a [`Procfile`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile)? If you're missing that file, this would explain why your server won't start.

Comment: no I didn't add. but when i add this error vanishes. but another error comes -                        like 
Traceback:

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in _execute
  85.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

The above exception (relation "myapp_student" does not exist
LINE 1: ..."last_name", "myapp_student"."university_id" FROM "myapp_stu...
                                                             ^
) was the direct cause of the following exception:

Comment: I have added the error above in question, can u plz check. Thanks

Comment: Your schema is incorrect (something is wrong with the database). You'll need to check your database's configuration.

Comment: I'm using sqlite db. Is it a problem ? or any other thing ?as when i'm running that app in local, its running fine without any error.